# Formatting a file to use it with fortune in the terminal

Tags: sed, regex, awk, fortune

I have a big text file with 'Terms' and its 'Definition' separated by spaces(variable).
I want to use it in fortune cookie format.

Current file format:

```
**term1**     this is my definition with occasional(<br>,/,e.g., ; etc symbols) and some are way longer
**term2**  this is my definition with occasional(<br>,/,e.g., ; etc symbols)
```

I want to transform it to the following format

```
**term1** : this is my definition with occasional(<br>,/,e.g., ; etc symbols)
%
**term2** : this is my definition with occasional(<br>,/,e.g., ; etc symbols)
%
```

maybe with some sed or awk (I'm not good in either one)

please help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
awk '{$1 = $1 " : "; print; print "%"}' filename
```

On second thought, that will compress up any sequences of whitespace into a single space. Use this instead:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/ : /; a %' filename
```

Comment: FYI: http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers